# Extract 2 terms before specific character

Tags: r, stringr, stringi

I want to extract the two words preceding a Twitter @handle

```
x <- c("this is a @handle", "My name is @handle", "this string has @more than one @handle")
```

Doing the following extracts all the text preceding the *last* @handle only, I need it for all @handles

```
(ext <- stringr::str_extract_all(x, "^.*@"))
[[1]]
[1] "this is a @"

[[2]]
[1] "My name is @"

[[3]]
[1] "this string has @more than one @"
```

Comment: you probably want `str_split`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a quantifier `{2}` to specify how many words you want to extract before the character `@`. A word consists of word characters `\\w+` and a word boundary, which in your case would be spaces. And we can use `trimws` function to remove unnecessary leading and trailing spaces:

```
library(stringr)
lapply(str_extract_all(x, "(\\w+\\s+){2}(?=@)"), trimws)

#[[1]]
#[1] "is a"

#[[2]]
#[1] "name is"

#[[3]]
#[1] "string has" "than one"
```